# Next.js, strict Typescript and missing / hard to find RenderPageResult type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, next.js, strong-typing

I have strict TypeScript setup. (Due to `'no implicit any return type' error/warning`) I needed return type of one function in a custom Document component to be like:

```js
  ctx.renderPage = (): RenderPageResult | Promise<RenderPageResult> =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: App => (props): ReactElement => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });
```

but couldn't figure out how to get a hold of `RenderPageResult`.

So I've added following to the `next-env.d.ts` file:

```js
/// <reference types="next/dist/next-server/lib/utils" />
```

And imported `RenderPageResult` like this into the Document component:

```js
import { RenderPageResult } from 'next/dist/next-server/lib/utils';
```

***Is this correct way going about it?***

***Is there a better/correct way of doing it?***

Thanks.

---

**PS**

Project uses `"next": "^9.1.4",` which is pretty much the latest release at the time of writing.

**PPS**

Question originally posted here: https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/next-js-strict-typescript-and-missing-hard-to-find-renderpageresult-type~6cf4b4a8-769f-4a99-a72e-8ee2f8ad17db

**Updates:**

1. the `next-env.d.ts` file update mentioned above seems to add zero value (and based on TS docs probs is complete misunderstanding of the declaration files on my part).

Comment: are you sure you have to specify `renderPage`'s type explicitly? what error would you get if you remove `RenderPageResult | Promise<RenderPageResult>`?

Comment: would you please post the content of next-env.d.ts as well?

Comment: what is the type of `ctx`?

Comment: Hi @EvgenyTimoshenko I have following in the `next-env.d.ts`:

```typescript
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/types/global" />
/// <reference types="next/types" />
/// <reference types="next/dist/next-server/lib/utils" /> // should probs remove this since does nothing pretty much
```

This was the error that was reported without the return type:
`Missing return type on function.eslint(@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type)`

Comment: you could try `ctx.renderPage = (): ReturnType<typeof ctx.renderPage>` instead of referencing d.ts file and importing the type explicitly